# What is the purpose of 'mov edi, edi'?

Tags: disassembly, windows

I see this instruction in the beginning of several Windows programs.
It's copying a register to itself, so basically, this acts as a `nop`.
What's the purpose of this instruction?

Comment: The Essence: It is a two-byte NOP. So you can patch two bytes atomically without having the processor load an incomplete/incorrect instruction when he tries to execute this part of the code while you are changing it.

Comment: In x86-64 `mov edi,edi` is not a NOP. In x86-64 it zeroes the top 32 bits of `rdi`. In 32-bit code `mov edi,edi` can used as a NOP.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Raymond Chen (Microsoft) has a blog post discussing this in detail:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583

In short, it's a compile time addition applied in order to support run time hot patching, so the function can have the first two bytes overwritten with a JMP instruction to redirect execution to another piece of code.

Comment: You should probably add a note about the 5 empty bytes preceding the `mov edi, edi` instruction.

Comment: Why not a real 2-byte NOP like `66 90`?  That would be more efficient: no back-end uop needed, no extra latency for EDI (in case that matters), no physical register needed to rename the output.  Perhaps it's supposed to be a "signature" that tools can recognize as not naturally occurring except in hotpatch code?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Raymond Chen discusses that also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130102-00/?p=5663 "the decision to use MOV EDI, EDI as the two-byte NOP instruction came after consulting with CPU manufacturers for their recommendations for the best two-byte NOP"

Comment: @BenSchwehn: Huh, probably that decision dates back to P5 Pentium days, where a `66` prefix made the instruction take an extra cycle to decode.  It's unfortunate for later CPUs from P6 and onward.  It's also unfortunate that it has to be a NOP, rather than optionally being a useful instruction like a 2-byte encoding of `push ebp` for functions that use a frame pointer.  (Using the `push r/m32` form with a modrm byte, not the 1-byte short form.)  But that's somewhat less simple to handle, and need an alternative to not pessimize functions that don't want to push anything.

Answer (score 19):

It's intended to jump to a *specific* location, 5 bytes before the mov instruction.  From there, you have 5 bytes which are intended to be modified to a long jump to somewhere else in 32-bit memory space.  Note that when hot-patching, that 5 bytes jump should be placed first, and then the mov can be replaced.  Going the other way, you risk the replaced mov-jmp running first, and jumping to the 5 bytes of whatever happens to be there (it's all nops by default, but you never know).

[addition follows]

Regarding writing the 5 bytes jump - there's also the problem of there is only one instruction that will let you write more than 4 bytes atomically - cmpxchg8b, and that's not an ideal instruction for the purpose.  If you write the 0xe9 first and then a dword, then you have a race condition if the 0xe9 is executed before you place the dword.  Yet another reason to write the long jump first.

Comment: It's NOPs or INT3's, generally.

Comment: Right, but in the case of INT3s, you definitely don't want to be running that by accident.

Comment: And in case the function is *already* detoured, writing the 4-byte jump target address first will atomically replace whatever `rel32` the previous `jmp` had.  (Assuming that the dword is 4-byte aligned, which it will be if functions are 8 or 16-byte aligned.  It ends at the start of a function.)

Answer (score 8):

courtsey **Hotpatching and the Rise of
Third-Party Patches** presentation at BlackHat USA 2006 by
**Alexander 
Sotirov**

**What Is Hotpatching?**
Hotpatching is a method for modifying the behavior of an
application by modifying its binary code at runtime. It is a
common technique with many uses:

•
debugging (software breakpoints)

•
runtime instrumentation

•
hooking Windows API functions

•
modifying the execution or adding new functionality to
closed-source applications

•
deploying software updates without rebooting

•
fixing security vulnerabilities

**Hotpatches** are generated by an automated tool that
compares the original and patched binaries. The functions that
have changed are included in a file with a .hp.dll extension.
When the hotpatch DLL is loaded in a running process, the first
instruction of the vulnerable function is replaced with a jump to
the hotpatch.

The **/hotpatch** compiler option ensures that the first instruction of
every function is a 
**mov 
edi, 
edi** 
instruction that can be safely
overwritten by the hotpatch. Older versions of Windows are not
compiled with this option and cannot be hotpatched.